# Jquery syntax explanation for PubSub Design Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, publish-subscribe

In my quest to grasp better some Javacript and jQuery concepts, I ran accross the following snippet of code.

```
var o = $( {} );
$.subscribe = o.on.bind(o);
$.unsubscribe = o.off.bind(o);
$.publish = o.trigger.bind(o);
// Usage
$(document.body).on( 'click', function() {
   // ...yadada
   $.publish( 'clicketyClack' ); // Think Rocky Balboa yelling out the window: "Hey yo!"
});

// And some dude listening patiently for Rocky's voice.
$.subscribe( 'clicketyClack', function() {
        console.log("You can't win, Rock");
});
```

Problem is I don't understand the syntax very well.
What does it mean? Are we kind of extending the on namespace with the bind function?

```
$.subscribe = o.on.bind(o); --> 
$.subscribe = $( {} ).on.bind($( {} ));
```

From the Jquery API:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
.bind( eventType [, eventData ], handler )
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: This seems to be a quite weird way to dynamically bind events. Not sure though, this code seems to do nothing if you try it (tested it locally and seems to not log "You can't win, rock")

Comment: @briosheje: You have to click somewhere.

Comment: @Bergi: I know, I've clicked, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This use of the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is equivalent to

```
$.subscribe = function(event, handler) {
    o.on(event, handler);
};
$.unsubscribe = function(event, handler) {
    o.off(event, handler);
};
$.publish = function(event, data) {
    o.trigger(event, data);
};
```

which is just defining those global helper functions with catchy names, so that you don't have to use `on`/`off`/`trigger` on that `o` object.

Comment: I was looking desperately for a bind() with this syntax in jQuery without success. Now it's all clearer, it's vanilla JS :-)

What I think it does though is that it assigns the this value to the o object ($({})) so that the publishers and the subscribers will have the same context.

Am I wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes, calling all these methods on `o` makes all the `handler`s receive the `{}` object for their context.